# insert a block of fixed size on the home page

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming

I would like to make a block whose content is equal to the last article inserted.
also must have a fixed size, and always stay on the home. How do?

see also image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fire up Views, make a new block view that displays nodes, under *sort criteria*, use node post date, then under *Pager*, select *Display a specified number of items* and set it to 1.

Go to *Structure -> Blocks* and set your new block view to display on the home/front page.